# Error in the proof for Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, then $A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement}\subseteq (A \cap B)^{\complement}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

I have a proof that I know has a fundamental error in it, but I have no idea where the error is. Here is the proof:

> Proof: Suppose that $x \in A^{\complement} \cup B^{\complement}$. This implies that $x \in A^{\complement}$ or $x \in B^{\complement}$. This disjunction will be true if $x \in A^{\complement}$. In this case, we have that $x \notin A$. But if $x \notin A$ then $x \notin A \cap B$, since $A \cap B$ is the set of all elements that are in both $A$ and $B$. And if $x \notin A \cap B$, then $x \in (A \cap B)^{\complement}$. Therefore, $A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement}\subseteq (A \cap B)^{\complement}$ as desired.

Comment: What if $x\in A$ but $x\in \overline A\cup \overline B$ nontheless?

Comment: The  error is "This disjunction will be true if $x\in A^c$". That won't mean that $a$ will *be* in $A^c$.  Any more than.  "I have a million dollars or my online name is fleabane.  That would be true if I had a million dollars."  But you can show the  same for $x \in B^c$.   (or you can say "wolog $a \in A^c".  Otherwise your proof is good.

Comment: Do not use notation $\overline{A}$ in this context. That is a notation for the closure of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fundamental error in it.

You proved legally that $x\in A^{\complement}\implies x\in(A\cap B)^{\complement}$ so that $A^{\complement}\subseteq(A\cap B)^{\complement}$.

What lacks somehow is a statement as:

"...likewise we prove that $B^{\complement}\subseteq(A\cap B)^{\complement}$ so that $A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement}\subseteq(A\cap B)^{\complement}$".

Answer (score 0):

> Proof: Suppose that $x∈A^c∪B^c$. This implies that x∈A¯¯¯¯ or
>   x∈B¯¯¯¯. $\color{gray}{\text{This disjunction will be true if x∈A¯¯¯¯}}$.$\color{green}{\text{Wolog we may assume, up to labeling, }x\in \overline A} $ In this case, we
>   have that x∉A. But if x∉A then x∉A∩B, since A∩B is the set of all
>   elements that are in both A and B. And if x∉A∩B, then
>   x∈A∩B¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯. Therefore, A¯¯¯¯∪B¯¯¯¯⊆A∩B¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯ as
>   desired.

There.  Now the proof does not contain the error.

Comment: Im not looking for how to fix the error, im looking for an explination as to what the error is

Comment: I edited the question to change $\overline{A}$ into $A^{\complement}$. You might want to adapt your answer. Btw, what are you doing here? Some experiments with MathJax maybe?

Comment: its an practice question. we have to find and explain the error in the proof

Comment: The error is exceedingly minor.  But it seems to be assuming $x \in A^c $ when it could be in $B^c $ instead.

Comment: Of course one can always end a proof with "do the same for $B^c $.

Comment: Oops.  Shame on me. Martians answer is correct.

Comment: Wait.  No shame on me.

Answer (score -1):

You have not taken into account the fact that you can have both $x\in  A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement}$ AND $x\in A$...

Since $ A^{\complement} \cup B^{\complement}$ is the addition of $A^{\complement}$ and $B^{\complement}$, so you can add back elements that were excluded from $A$ but are in $B^{\complement}$.